# Почему не работает элемент tref

Tags: svg

Почему текст не показывается в ссылке tref ?

```html
<svg width="900" height="200" viewBox="0 0 900 200" style='border: 1px solid black' >
  <defs>
     <text x="50" y="50" fill='blue'  font-size='30' id='a'>
    Быстрее
   </text>
  </defs>
  
  <text>
    <tref x='100' y='100' xlink:href='#a'></tref>
  </text> 

</svg>
```

Comment: [*Deprecated*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/tref) жи.

Comment: @Ainar-G Здравствуйте я не знаю английский :((

Comment: «*Deprecated*» = «Устаревший».  Элемент больше не поддерживается браузерами, и возможно никогда не поддерживался.  См. таблицу внизу страницы.

Comment: @Ainar-G понятно спасибо за ответ